# react js increment count existing object in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a simple `Point of sale` system and in my `Cart reducer`.

I need to check if the `object` is already in the `Cart Array` then increment the quantity. And if the `Object` does not exist push it into the `Cart Array`

The code is working as expected. But is there a better workaround ?

**Cart Reducer**

```
export const cartReducer = (state: IState, action: Actions) => {
const { uid } = action.payload

switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TO_CART': {
        const cart_item = state.cart.filter(item => item.uid === uid)

        if (cart_item.length > 0) {
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: state.cart.map(item => item.uid === uid ? { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 } : item)
            }
        }

        return {
            ...state,
            cart: [...state.cart, action.payload]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks mostly reasonable to me, but you could make a slight improvement by

- declaring the new `cart` ahead of time instead of returning twice
- use `some` instead of `filter`

```
case 'ADD_TO_CART': {
    const exists = state.cart.some(item => item.uid === uid);
    const cart = exists
        ? state.cart.map(item => item.uid === uid ? { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 } : item)
        : [...state.cart, action.payload];
    return {
        ...state,
        cart
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping over all items twice (ones to filter and once to map) you can simply use `findIndex`.

The benefit of `findIndex` over `filter`: iteration will stop once the condition is fulfilled and you'll get its index, unlike filter where the loop iterates over all the elements in the array.

If your array has fewer elements, your solution is fine, but `findIndex` will give better performance in the case of long arrays.

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TO_CART': {
        const cartItemIndex = state.cart.findIndex(item => item.uid === uid)
        const updatedCart = [...state.cart]

        if (cartItemIndex > -1) {
            updatedCart[cartItemIndex] = { ...updatedCart[cartItemIndex], quantity: item.quantity + 1 }
        }
        else {
            updatedCart.push(action.payload)
        }

        return {
            ...state,
            cart: updatedCart
        }
    }
}
```